# ActionBar show search automatically (SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to use ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW in ActionBar. So I would have search and search suggestions in ActionBar. Is it possible to make show this input text, without need of clicking menu first?

My Activity is only for search purpose so it's not nice when user need first click on search.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by using custom view and displaying there some input field.